# Facebook Platform Authentication Permissions

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a web app about bookmarks. I'd like to have my own login system, but I'd like the users to be able to use FB Connect and the whole platform to invite their friends, and to post wall posts to their wall and share links.

What I should use, a log in button with the offline_access to allow the users publish wall messages, or that every time they log in to the page have to click something like "Use Facebook"?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. No need for the `offline_access` permission, you need the `publish_stream` permission to post to the user wall. [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)
   **publish_stream**
   Enables your application to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. **With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access.** However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.
2. And if the user is already has a valid session then you should display the *Publish to your wall* button and if not the *login to facebook* button